# how to display one div value in second div with click of first div value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

here is my html code:

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
       <div id="link">
       <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
       </div>
       <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

i want output something like this
click on Google then its display there result in  other div

thanks

Comment: The result of navigating to www.google.com? Or the result of searching for something? You might want a `iframe`

Comment: what've you tried so far about ajax?

Comment: no use iframe use any other...

Comment: @polin i am not tried ajax help if you have some idea of them

Comment: What?? you want a web page in your html div??

Comment: Please answer Aesthete's question, it's important. They do everything at Google to prevent google.com opening anywhere else but in it's own tab or window...

Comment: @SankalpMishra yes exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this its work...

first you creat a PHP File:-

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($_POST['action']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $r->event_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
?>
```

1. code for javascript:-

   `function result(url)
   {
   $.ajax({ url: 'one.php',

            data: {action: url},

            type: 'post',

            success: function(output) {

                         $('#result').html(output);

                     }

   });

   }`

3.code for your html file:-

```
   <body>
       <div id="link">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="result('https://www.google.co.in/')">google</a>
       </div>
        <div id="result" height="200" width="200"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below javascript code

```
var el=document.getElementById("result");
el.innerHTML="<iframe src=\'http://www.google.com\'></iframe>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try it...
[Google Web Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/)

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

    google.load('search', '1');

    $('a').live('click',function OnLoad() {
      // Create a search control
      var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

      // Add in a full set of searchers
      var localSearch = new google.search.LocalSearch();
      searchControl.addSearcher(localSearch);
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.VideoSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.BlogSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.NewsSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.ImageSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.BookSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.PatentSearch());

      // Set the Local Search center point
      localSearch.setCenterPoint("New York, NY");

      // tell the searcher to draw itself and tell it where to attach
      searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("searchcontrol"));

      // execute an inital search
      searchControl.execute("VW GTI");
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be making 2 different web pages (your initial page & your result) and then pu them in an iframe. You can see a demo here: [LINK](http://brettcass.com/demo/iframe1/)